# How to get the selected icon from js bootsstrap iconpicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I installed the js bootstrap iconpicker (http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Based-Icon-Picker-For-Bootstrap-3-iconpicker.html, http://victor-valencia.github.io/bootstrap-iconpicker/) but I do not see how to detect the selected icon.

The example code to configure the button is:

```
$('#convert').iconpicker({ 
    iconset: 'fontawesome',
    icon: 'fa-key', 
    rows: 5,
    cols: 5,
    placement: 'top',
});
```

But there's nothing in the examples telling how to get the selected icon. I'ld think of a callback or something like that.

How can I get the selected icon?

Answer (score 2):

I've updated the plugin at *Github*, so a `change` event is fired when the user change the iconpicker.

I've already sent a pull request to the owner of the plugin (Victor Valencia).
While he doesn't approve the changes you can use [the version modified by me.](https://github.com/promatik/bootstrap-iconpicker)

**How you use it:**

```
$('#iconpicker').on('change', function(e) {
    console.log( e.icon );
});
```

**Log:**

> *fa-key* 
>   *fa-info-circle* 
>   *fa-flag-checkered*

---

**Edit:**
*Victor Valencia* already approved my pull request so you can [download the source from his repository](https://github.com/victor-valencia/bootstrap-iconpicker).

Answer (score 1):

Theres a hidden input that changes based on what you select - you can access it with this: `$('input[name=icon]')`

Answer (score 0):

As fas as mi knowledge, It just change the css of the component. You will not get the image value here or the path.

Can you please elaborate what you trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

the event  is "iconpickerSelected"

```
$('#convert').iconpicker({ 
              iconset: 'fontawesome',
              icon: 'fa-key', 
              rows: 5,
              cols: 5,
              placement: 'top',
            });  
$('#convert').on('iconpickerSelected', function (e) {
 //here you can get the value

        $(this).val() 
})
```